# Google Calendar API & PHP Can't Connect / Add Event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am attempting to connect to our Google calendar and add / edit events.  I really don't want to switch to Zend framework, and from what I can tell, it's possible without ZF.  I've installed the client library, and this is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName("Leah Dawn Calendar Sync");
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('');
$client->setDeveloperKey('');

$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary('Test Event');
$event->setLocation('My House');

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2014-06-21T10:00:00.000-05:00');
$event->setStart($start);

$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2014-06-21T10:25:00.000-05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('myemail@gmail.com', $event); //Returns array not an object
echo $createdEvent->id;
```

I have printed out the results of $event, and I do see that everything is connecting successfully, and building correctly, but the very last line will not execute to actually create the event.  All documentation I can find says this is exactly how to do it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate using Oauth2 for myemail@gmail.com to be able to create events for that account. There is a php example here http://cornempire.net/2012/01/08/part-2-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/